# Clusterlabs pacemaker will not install on centos5

Tags: linux, compilation, cluster-computing, rpm, pacemaker

I'm trying to install pacemaker on my centos 5.11 test server.  I'm setting up a 2 node cluster for postgres.  Pacemaker install failed due to dependency of package resource-agents.  I cannot find the rpm in any of the centos repo at clusterlabs.  I found the source rpm and compiled and installed succesfully.  Pacemaker still fails to find resource-agents.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
pacemaker-1.1.8-2.el5.i686 from clusterlabs-next has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: resource-agents is needed by package pacemaker-1.1.8-2.el5.i686 (clusterlabs-next)
pacemaker-1.1.8-2.el5.x86_64 from clusterlabs-next has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: resource-agents is needed by package pacemaker-1.1.8-2.el5.x86_64 (clusterlabs-next)
Error: Missing Dependency: resource-agents is needed by package pacemaker-1.1.8-2.el5.x86_64 (clusterlabs-next)
Error: Missing Dependency: resource-agents is needed by package pacemaker-1.1.8-2.el5.i686 (clusterlabs-next)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm not sure where resource-agents is supposed to be installed.  I copied the source to a temp dir and extracted and compiled there.  Is it possible resource-agents is not installed in the correct location?

Comment: You installed resource-agents from source manually? That's not going to help rpm at all. It doesn't know anything about that. You need an rpm of it for rpm to notice it.

Comment: resource-agents is an rpm in the clusterlabs-next repository (the same as pacemaker) it should have just worked I think. Can you show the contents of the `.repo` file you have for `clusterlabs-next`? Because I don't see the `1.1.8` version in the [repository](http://clusterlabs.org/rpm-next/epel-5/x86_64/) I found online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.  I'm stuck with centos5, powers that be are not interested in upgrading.  I'll keep looking for a rpm for resource-agents for centos5.  Its hard to believe that clusterlabs has installs for centos5 just no resource-agents.

Comment: Ah, wait, the RHEL repo has that vesrion and doesn't have resource-agents. If you are on CentOS you should probably try the [epel repo](http://clusterlabs.org/rpm-next/epel-5/x86_64/) and not the [rhel repo](http://clusterlabs.org/rpm-next/rhel-5/x86_64/). Presumably resources-agents is something that comes with RHEL.

Comment: Since Keith doesn't like my question,  I'll try unix.stackexchange.  Etan,  I'll look closer at clusterlabs.  I've not been able to find that rpm yet.

Comment: so keith, how do I close?

Answer (score -1):

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-5*.rpm
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/pacemaker.repo http://clusterlabs.org/rpm/epel-5/clusterlabs.repo
```

then finally,

```
yum install -y pacemaker.$(uname -i) corosync.$(uname -i)
```

Comment: yes after this installation, you must use crm commands from corosync, not pacemaker which is pcs. but it is almost the same.

Comment: clusterlabs.repo give 404